# Why doesn't my variable return the answer?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to construct a program. Everything works but my math portion of the program. I want the time in mins entered to be converted to hours. This should be a decimal number like 30 mins=.5 hrs. I'll try to omit as much code as I can that I don't think is relevant to make it easier to read.

```
public class StudentReader
{
    private static String studentName= "";
    private static int pages;
    private static int time;
StudentReader(String name,int pagenum, int totalTime)
    {
        studentName=name;
        pages=pagenum;
        time=totalTime;
    }
public double getTotalTimeInHours()
    {
        double total=0;
        total=time / 60;
        return total;

    }
}
```

This class is being called by another class:

```
System.out.println("What is the total amount of time spent reading?: ");
totalTime=scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(StudentReader.getTotalTime());
```

Comment: There is no `getTotalTime()` method in your class. You only have a `getTotalTimeInHours`.

Comment: Also, you are not using the totalTime field into which you are presumably reading the number of minutes.

Comment: @Leeish Wow I can't believe I over looked that. Thx

Comment: @SkyVar: In future, please indicate what *actual problem* you're seeing. My answer primarily deals with an issue of returning a value which isn't the one you expect - whereas simply calling a non-existent method is a completely different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
total=time / 60;
```

Both `time` and `60` are `int` values, so it uses integer division, and then promotes the *result* to a `double` value in order to assign it to `total`.

This simple change will force it to use `double` arithmetic:

```
total=time / 60.0;
```

However, given that you don't actually do anything else with `total` other than return it, the code would be simpler as:

```
public double getTotalTimeInHours() {
    return time / 60.0;
}
```

Additionally, as Leeish pointed out, you're trying to call it as `getTotalTime`, which isn't the method name...